# Why php variable scope not working in function

Tags: php

I executed following code but php says:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: b in ..\..\..\demo.php on line 4 
Notice: Undefined variable: a in ..\..\..\demo.php on line 4
```

Php Code:

```
<?php
  $a='a';$b='b';
  function test(){
      echo $a.$b;
  }
  test(); // error
?>
```

But i changed the code to this:

```
<?php
  $a='a';$b='b';
  function test($a,$b){
      echo $a.$b;
  }
  test($a,$b); // ab
?>
```

Why `$a` and `$b` are undefined in first case, since i defined them before? 
Why parameters need to pass in php? It's not require in other like `JavaScript`.

Comment: Add `global $a, $b;` in your first function and it will work :)

Comment: PHP and Javascript doe not follow the same scoping rules. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If variables are defined outside the function, you need to specify the `global` keyword.  Such as:

```
<?php
$a='a';$b='b';
function test(){
    global $a, $b;
    echo $a.$b;
}
test(); // error
?>
```

But your second example is the recommended way of handling it, typically.

Answer (score 1):

$a and $b in the first example you provided are attempting to access those variables respectively from the local scope not the global scope. You could try declaring them like this

```
 function test() {
     global $a, $b;
     echo $a . $b; //or $GLOBALS['a'].$GLOBALS['b'];
 }
```

and you will get the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$a = '101';
$func = function() use($a) {
    echo $a;
};

function func_2() {
    global $func;
    $a = 'not previouse a';
    $func();
}

func_2();
```