# PHP - Form validation functions. How to use functions to write better code?

Tags: php, forms, function, validation

I'm practicing doing simple form validation and have come unstuck trying to use a **function** to replace code that I repeat several times throughout the validation script.

I am trying to write a function that ***saves an error message to an $errors array when validation fails for that form field***.

The function I'm using does **not** return any error messages but does not display the message that is should do when validation fails.

I'm testing it on just one filed, the **username** field and with just one validation rule, username cannot be blank.

*NB/ The form and validation worked when I was not trying to use a function.*

Here is what I have, what a I doing wrong? I'm struggling to get to grips with functions :-(

**functions.php**

```
<?php
//Function to deal with saving error messages to errors array
// @param - 2 parameters. Name of field that has the error; Error message string
// @return - an error message string

function errorHandler($errField, $errMsg){

    $errors[$errField] = $errMsg;

return $errors;

}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
include_once '_includes/headers.php';
include_once '_includes/functions.php';
?>

<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

//Initialize variables
$data = array();//Store cleaned valid data for output
$errors = array();//Store error messages
$form_is_submitted = false;
$errors_detected = false;

if(isset($_POST['registerBtn'])){

    $form_is_submitted = true;

    //VALIDATE FORM

    //Validate - Username
    if (isset($_POST['username'])) {

        $username = trim($_POST['username']);

        //Username cannot be blank - validation
        if($username !== ''){

            $data['username'] = htmlentities($username);

            //Get the length of the string
            $stringLength = strlen($username);

            //Username minimum 5 maximum 15 characters long - validation
            if($stringLength < 5 || $stringLength > 15){

                $errors_detected = true;

                $errors['username'] = ' Invalid length. Must be between 5 - 15 characters!';

            }else {

                $data['username'] = htmlentities($username);
            }

            //Username must only be alphanumeric characters - validation
            if(!ctype_alnum($username)){

                $errors_detected = true;

                $errors['username'] = ' Invalid characters. Alphanumeric characters only!';
            }else {

                $data['username'] = htmlentities($username);
            }


        }else {

            $errors_detected = true;

            //Call error message function
            if($errors_detected === true){

                errorHandler('username', ' Field cannot be blank!');

            }

        }

    }else {

        $errors_detected = true;

        $errors['username'] = ' Is not set!';

    }



    //Validate - Email
    if(isset($_POST['email'])){

        $email = trim($_POST['email']);

        //Email cannot be blank - validation
        if($email !== ''){

            $data['email'] = htmlentities($email);

            //Email must be valid format - validation
            if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){

                $errors_detected = true;

                $errors['email'] = ' Invalid email format!';

            }else {

                $data['email'] = htmlentities($email);
            }


        }else{

            $errors_detected = true;

            $errors['email'] = ' Email address is required!';
        }
    }else {

        $errors_detected = true;

        $errors['email'] = " is not set!";
    }

}

//Declare form output variable
$output = '';

//IF VALID SUBMISSION
if($form_is_submitted === true && $errors_detected === false){

    $output .= '<h3>Form successfully submitted</h3>';

    echo $output;

    foreach($data as $keys => $values){

        echo "<p>$keys : $values</p>";

    }

} else {

    //IF INVALID SUBMISSION


        if($errors_detected === true){

            $output .= '<h2>There are errors on the form</h2>';

            echo $output;

            foreach($errors as $key => $value){

                echo "<p>" . htmlentities($key) . ':' . htmlentities($value) . "</p>";
            }


        }



        //DISPLAY/REDISPLAY FORM

        $self = htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

        $output ='

        <form action="'. $self .'" method="post">
    <fieldset id="registration">
        <legend>Register</legend>

        <p>Insert your profile information:</p>

            <div>
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input id="username" name="username" type=text value="' . (isset($data['username']) ? $data['username'] : '') . '" />
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input id="email" name="email" type=email value="' . (isset($data['email']) ? $data['email'] : '') . '" />
            </div>

            <input type="submit" id="registerBtn" name="registerBtn" value="Register" />

    </fieldset>


</form>

    ';

        echo $output;


}


?>



<?php
include_once '_includes/footers.php';
?>
```

***UPDATE:***
I have updated my function to use the $errors array in my function. This should now no longer be a scope issue I think. As per Francesco Malatesta below ...

Comment: It looks like the `$errors` variable will be out of scope in your function. You'll need to pass that variable to your function or define it as a global. See [variable scope @ php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) and [What is variable scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and) and possibly [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165427/why-php-variable-scope-not-working-in-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should study something about objects, classes, exceptions and more complex stuff for this kind of job. I am assuming you want to learn about functions and do some practice.

You should, first of all, pass the errors array as a parameter.

Like this:

```
function errorHandler($errorsArray, $errField, $errMsg){

    $errorsArray[$errField] = $errMsg;

   return $errorsArray;

}
```

And then, in your *index.php* file:

```
errorHandler($errors, 'username', ' Field cannot be blank!');
```

This should work, because you must use the *$errors* array in your function. It's a scope-related problem.

However, after this, forget everything (well, not everything) and study OOP and Exceptions :)

Comment: Hi, I've seen exceptions in a few online tutorials but I don't think I'm at that level of understanding yet. So I have made the changes you suggest but no difference. Still it appears that the $errors['username'] is not being updated when validation fails.

Comment: Wait, are you assigning to _$errors_ the value of _errorHandler('username', ' Field cannot be blank!');_? :) Do this: _$errors = errorHandler('username', ' Field cannot be blank!');_

Comment: Yes perfect thanks that works! So, I must assign the returned value of the function to the array $errors.  Eg: $errors = errorHandler($errors, 'username', ' Field cannot be blank!');

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about Exceptions?

Simple example to use a exception:

```
<?php

 try {
 // your if's
 if(40 > 30) {
   throw new Exception("40 is a bigger");
 }
} catch (Exception $error) {
   echo 'Your error is: '.$error->getMessage();
}

?>
```